# What is the possible creator of the MxNitro installer?

Tags: browser, installation, maxthon

What program possibly is the creator of the MxNitro browser installer?

How can I make a simple installer like that?

Answer (score 0):

[MxNitro](http://usa.maxthon.com/mxnitro/) Installer is a custom installer made by [Maxthon](http://www.maxthon.com), based on [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/).

Its source contains the path: `d:\mxdev\mt\trunk\deploy\builder\MTInstall_NSIS\install_data\Install.pdb`

You can make a very simple installer using [InstallSimple](http://www.installsimple.com/) too.